# Sub classing MultipartStreamProvider fails in Visual Studio c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http, multipartform-data, azure-functions

I am trying to subclass MultipartStreamProvider in Visual Studio,

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetStream' in type 
     'Uploadfunction.InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider' from assembly 
     'Uploadfunction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
     does not have an implementation.
  in Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions.Build.targets line 31
```

My line 31 is like this

```
        <BuildFunctions
  TargetPath="$(TargetPath)"
  OutputPath="$(TargetDir)"/>
```

I have System.net Assemblies and have also downloaded Microsoft.net.sdk.functions (1.0.6).

My function class looks like this -

```
public static class UploadFunction
{
    [FunctionName("UploadFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {


    //Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

      var provider = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new InMemoryStream());

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "File Uploaded");

 }
```

And my InMemoryStream class looks like this.

```
public class InMemoryStream : System.Net.Http.MultipartStreamProvider
{
    public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
         MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
        return s;
    }


}
```

Comment: Isn't that message because you are throwing a `NotImplementedException` on `InMemoryStream.GetStream`?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Sorry, I edited it. It wasnt throwing that Exception.

Comment: Could you possible publish a full repro includuing your project files? It looks like there's just an issue with resolving `Uploadfunction.InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` which you don't have in your sample above.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Here is a link to my copy - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFAnTAtbfQPnsdIFI7_ugBYTd6QNc4VW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: All I did was, start a new Azure function, and use the MultipartStreamProvider, didn't modify any libraries.

Comment: Man, that's super weird. I don't think this is Functions related. I changed MultipartStreamProvider to MultipartMemoryStreamProvider and it worked. Maybe there is some quirks around MultipartStreamProvider? Could you try that and see if it works? If so, I'll put it down as the answer.

Comment: Yep that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's causing the issue with `MultipartStreamProvider`, but if you change to `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` it works fine.

My guess would be there is somehow a mismatch of the System.Net library, which is causing one of the `GetStream` implementations to not line up. You normally see that with libraries which have mismatched dll versions.